# MvvmCross: Android custom webview urls handlers

Tags: mvvm, mvvmcross

My Android application had some complex text with hyperlinks embedded inside.  The easiest way for me to handle this was to just use an embedded WebView and detect hyperlink clicks to perform custom commands.  I am trying to do this the MvvmCross way.  Is there a binding available for WebView.SetBackgroundColor or WebView.LoadData?  Once I get my custom html inside and the user clicks on hyperlinks, I have used WebView.SetWebViewClient to install my own client which can detect hyperlink clicks and perform custom actions.  Any way to turn all of that into proper MvxCommand usage?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a binding available for WebView.SetBackgroundColor

For View color binding see the sample: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ValueConversion

> or WebView.LoadData?

See [Dynamic Binding UIWebView in MVVMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548972/dynamic-binding-uiwebview-in-mvvmcross)

> I have used WebView.SetWebViewClient to install my own client which can detect hyperlink clicks and perform custom actions. Any way to turn all of that into proper MvxCommand usage?

It's not clear to me what your question is. Maybe try coding something first and then coming back with some sample code for the problem - eg come back with a specific question about a specific `ViewModel` so that others can try to answer at a code level instead of at this more general level. Perhaps also try asking one question at a time and asking with a deeper level of detail - *How to ask* may help you get better results - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom WebView by inheriting and added Command properties.  I then added a custom WebViewClient to detect certain URL's and to call the corresponding command that was bound.  Is this a good way to accomplish this?

```
public class AboutWebView : WebView
{
    public IMvxCommand AboutCommand { get; set; }
    public IMvxCommand LicenseCommand { get; set; }
    public IMvxCommand PrivacyCommand { get; set; }

    public AboutWebView (Context ctx,IAttributeSet aset) : base(ctx,aset)
    {
        SetWebViewClient (new AboutWebViewClient(this));
    }

    private class AboutWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        private AboutWebView _parent = null;

        public AboutWebViewClient(AboutWebView parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
        }

        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
        {
            if (url.StartsWith ("about://"))
                _parent.AboutCommand.Execute ();
            else if (url.Equals (App.LICENSE_URL))
                _parent.LicenseCommand.Execute ();
            else
                _parent.PrivacyCommand.Execute ();
            return(true);
        }
    }
}
```