# What replaces the MvvmCross view model PropertyChanged event in V3 Hot Tuna?

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

Previously using V2, I loaded content into a WebView using the event handler accessed in the view code (see below) as I could not find a way of loading data through binding in xml.

```
    this.ViewModel.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(EventHandlerFoo);

    private void EventHandlerFoo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       PropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs = (PropertyChangedEventArgs) e;
       if (eventArgs.PropertyName == "Foo")
       {
           WebView webView = item.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.fooWebView);
           string body = item.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.fooUrl).Text;
           webView.LoadData(body, "text/html", "utf-8");
       }
    }
```

This is no longer available in V3 and I have been unable to locate a replacement. Is there an event handler hidden away in the depths of Hot Tuna that I can use or will I have to implement my own?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error message(s) does this code give you?

Comment: Error Message: `'Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyChanged' and no extension method 'PropertyChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PropertyChanged` should still be there - it's part of `INotifyPropertyChanged` and is used throughout MvvmCross.

I'm on mobile web at present, but I'm guessing that the reason you don't see it now is because the `IMvxViewModel` attached to your `MvxActivity` doesn't have to inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/IMvxViewModel.cs

If you want to get back to the previous functionality where you had a full strongly typed ViewModel you can do this using (for example)

```
 public new MyViewModel ViewModel
 {
    get { return base.ViewModel as MyViewModel; }
    set { base.ViewModel = value; }
 }
```

or you could just cast it in your code:

```
 ((MyViewModel)this.ViewModel).PropertyChanged += // ...
```

Alternatively, if you want to do a full custom binding for a url for a webview, see: [Dynamic Binding UIWebView in MVVMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548972/dynamic-binding-uiwebview-in-mvvmcross) (iOS code - but the Android version is similar)

Comment: Many thanks Stuart, the casting worked a treat and you've highlighted to me that I was inheriting from `MvxViewModel` as opposed to `IMvxViewModel`. The custom binding for the WebView I'm struggling with but I'm blaming that on Android...