# how can I call Html.FromHtml inside Value Converter in PCL?

Tags: android, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I created FromHtmlValueConverter in my PCL based on the answer at [How can I bind an HTML string to a webview in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280053/how-can-i-bind-an-html-string-to-a-webview-in-an-android-app).

```
public class FromHtmlValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<string>
{
    protected override object Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Html.FromHtml(value);
    }
}
```

And I got compile error at Html.FromHtml. I can call Html.FromHtml properly from my .Droid project but I don't know how to call it inside PCL.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Html.FromHtml refers to Html class from Android, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)

So the converter should be in the Android app, not in PCL.

Comment: Thank you. I thought people only put value converters in PCL

Comment: you can do that too, you can have PCL converters and use them from app code. but in your example that converter was using platform (Android) specific code